# Find out all the different files from two different paths efficiently in Windows (with Python)

Tags: python, file-processing

Well, recently I'm working on a program which is able to sync files between different folders.

However, as a fresh man, the algorithm I worte looks really disgusting (bruh~)

The following lines are the related things I wrote,

I really hope there would be experts who can help me improve my code

```
def scan_items(folder_path):  # 扫描路径下所有文件夹
    def scan_folders_in(f_path):  # 扫描目录下所有的文件夹，并返回路径列表
        surf_items = os.scandir(f_path)
        folders = [f_path]
        for item_data in surf_items:
            if item_data.is_dir():
                folders.extend(scan_folders_in(item_data.path))  # 继续遍历文件夹内文件夹，直到记下全部文件夹路径
        folders = sorted(set(folders))  # 排序 + 排除重复项
        surf_items.close()
        return folders

    file_store = []
    folder_store = scan_folders_in(folder_path)
    for folder in folder_store:  # 遍历所有文件夹
        files = [folder + '\\' + dI for dI in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, dI))]
        # 如上只生成本文件夹内 文件的路径
        file_store.extend(files)  # 存储上面文件路径
    for i in range(len(file_store)):
        file_store[i] = file_store[i][len(folder_path)::]  # 返回相对位置
    result = [folder_store, file_store]
    return result
```

And here is the main part,
and the 'get_task()' part is the most important one

```
def sf_sync_dir(path1, path2, single_sync, language_number, area_name=None, pass_item_rpath='', pass_folder_paths=''):
    from LT_Dic import sf_label_text_dic  # Label information from another file

    def sf_show_notice(path_1, path_2, sf_errorname):  # Win10toast used

        toaster.show_toast('Sync Successfully',
                           'The Files in "' + path_1 + '" and "' + path_2 + '" are Synchronized',
                           icon_path=mf_data_path + r'Movefile.ico',
                           duration=10,
                           threaded=False)
        if len(sf_errorname) > 0:
            toaster.show_toast("Couldn't sync files",
                               sf_errorname + sf_label_text_dic['can_not_move_notice'][language_number],
                               icon_path=mf_data_path + r'Movefile.ico',
                               duration=10,
                               threaded=False)

    def get_task(barroot):  # shitty block here, help me!  (baroot is a root showing progress)
        all_files_1 = scan_items(path1)[1]
        all_files_2 = scan_items(path2)[1]
        sync_tasks = []
        pass_folder_rpaths = []
        task_number = 0

        for pass_folder in pass_folder_paths.split(','):
            if pass_folder.startswith(path1):
                pass_folder_rpaths.append(pass_folder.replace(path1, path1.split('\\')[-1]))
            elif pass_folder:
                pass_folder_rpaths.append(pass_folder.replace(path2, path2.split('\\')[-1]))

        file_info_1 = {}  # 存储文件1的信息：(哈希值, 大小, 修改时间)

        for file1 in all_files_1:
            file1_path = path1 + file1
            file_info_1[file1] = (filehash(file1_path), os.path.getsize(file1_path), os.path.getmtime(file1_path))

        for file2 in all_files_2:
            file2_path = path2 + file2

            if file2 in all_files_1:
                file1 = file2
                file1_path = path1 + file1
                file_info = file_info_1[file1]
                file2_info = (filehash(file2_path), os.path.getsize(file2_path), os.path.getmtime(file2_path))

                if file_info == file2_info:
                    continue

                if single_sync and file_info[0] == file2_info[0]:
                    continue

                new_file, old_file = file1, file2
                new_file_path, old_file_path = file1_path, file2_path
                new_file_rpath = path1.split('\\')[-1] + file1
                old_file_rpath = path2.split('\\')[-1] + file2

                if int(os.stat(new_file_path).st_mtime) < int(os.stat(old_file_path).st_mtime):
                    if single_sync:
                        continue
                    old_file, new_file = new_file, old_file
                    new_file_path, old_file_path = old_file_path, new_file_path
                    new_file_rpath, old_file_rpath = old_file_path, new_file_rpath

                if any(pfolder.startswith(old_file_rpath) for pfolder in pass_folder_rpaths) or any(
                        old_file.endswith(pfile) for pfile in pass_item_rpath.split(',')):
                    continue

                task_number += 1
                barroot.set_label1(sf_label_text_dic['main_progress_label'][language_number] + file1.split('\\')[-1])
                sync_tasks.append([new_file_path, old_file_path, False])
            else:
                new_file_rpath = path2.split('\\')[-1] + file2

                if any(pfolder.startswith(new_file_rpath) for pfolder in pass_folder_rpaths):
                    continue

                task_number += 1
                barroot.set_label1(sf_label_text_dic['main_progress_label'][language_number] + file2.split('\\')[-1])
                barroot.progress_root.update_idletasks()
                sync_tasks.append([file2_path, path1 + file2, True])

        if not single_sync:
            for file1 in all_files_1:
                if file1 not in all_files_2:
                    file1_path = path1 + file1
                    newfile1_rpath = path2.split('\\')[-1] + file1

                    if any(pfolder.startswith(newfile1_rpath) for pfolder in pass_folder_rpaths):
                        continue

                    task_number += 1
                    barroot.set_label1(
                        sf_label_text_dic['main_progress_label'][language_number] + file1.split('\\')[-1])
                    barroot.progress_root.update_idletasks()
                    sync_tasks.append([file1_path, path2 + file1, True])

        return sync_tasks

    def synchronize_files(baroot, task):
        baroot.set_label2(sf_label_text_dic["current_file_label1"][language_number] + task[0].split('\\')[-1])
        new_file_path, old_file_path, create_folder = task
        if create_folder:
            try:
                sf_creat_folder(old_file_path)
            except:
                pass
        try:
            shutil.copy2(new_file_path, old_file_path)
        except:
            return new_file_path
        return None

    def run_sync_tasks(baroot):
        sf_errorname = ''
        baroot.main_progress_bar['value'] = 0
        baroot.progress_root.update_idletasks()
        tasks = get_task(baroot)
        baroot.main_progress_bar['maximum'] = len(tasks)
        baroot.set_label1(
            f'{sf_label_text_dic["main_progress_label1"][language_number][0]}{str(baroot.main_progress_bar["value"])}/{str(len(tasks))}  {sf_label_text_dic["main_progress_label1"][language_number][1]}')

        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(synchronize_files, baroot, task) for task in tasks]

            for future in as_completed(futures):
                result = future.result()
                if result:
                    sf_errorname += result + ' , '

                baroot.main_progress_bar['value'] += 1
                baroot.set_label1(
                    f'{sf_label_text_dic["main_progress_label1"][language_number][0]}{str(baroot.main_progress_bar["value"])}/{str(len(tasks))}  {sf_label_text_dic["main_progress_label1"][language_number][1]}')
                baroot.progress_root.update_idletasks()

        baroot.progress_root.withdraw()
        path_name_1 = path1.split('\\')[-1]
        if area_name:
            path_name_1 = area_name
        try:
            sf_show_notice(path_name_1, path2.split('\\')[-1], sf_errorname)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            baroot.progress_root.withdraw()

    global sync_bar_root, sync_bar_root_task
    sync_bar_root = ProgressBar('Movefile  -Syncfile Progress',
                                sf_label_text_dic["main_progress_label2"][language_number],
                                sf_label_text_dic["current_file_label"][language_number],
                                language_number)
    sync_bar_root_task = threading.Thread(target=lambda: sync_bar_root.launch(), daemon=True)
    sync_bar_root_task.start()
    while not sync_bar_root.initialization_done:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    run_tasks = threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_sync_tasks(sync_bar_root), daemon=True)
    run_tasks.start()
```

And the progress bar class:

```
class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self, title, label1, label2, lang_num):
        self.initialization_done = False
        from LT_Dic import progress_root_label_dic
        self.title = title
        self.label1 = label1
        self.label2 = label2
        self.label_dic = progress_root_label_dic
        self.lang_num = lang_num
        self.main_progress_label = None
        self.main_progress_bar = None
        self.current_file_label = None
        self.show_running_bar = None
        self.progress_root = None
        self.roll_bar = None

    def set_label1(self, content):
        self.main_progress_label['text'] = content

    def set_label2(self, content):
        self.current_file_label['text'] = content

    def launch(self):
        self.progress_root = tk.Tk()
        self.progress_root.title(self.title)
        self.progress_root.geometry('420x115')
        self.progress_root.iconbitmap(mf_data_path + r'Movefile.ico')
        self.main_progress_label = ttk.Label(self.progress_root, text=self.label1)
        self.main_progress_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='SW')
        self.main_progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.progress_root)
        self.main_progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, ipadx=150, sticky='W')
        self.current_file_label = ttk.Label(self.progress_root, text=self.label2)
        self.current_file_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='SW')
        self.show_running_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.progress_root, mode='indeterminate')
        self.show_running_bar.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, ipadx=150, sticky='W')
        self.progress_root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.sync_bar_on_exit())
        self.roll_bar = threading.Thread(target=self.show_running, daemon=True)
        self.roll_bar.start()
        self.initialization_done = True
        self.progress_root.mainloop()

    def show_running(self):
        self.show_running_bar.start(10)

    def sync_bar_on_exit(self):
        if tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title='Syncfile', message=self.label_dic['confirm_exit_text'][self.lang_num]):
            self.progress_root.withdraw()
            self.roll_bar.join()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def progress_root_destruction(self):
        self.progress_root.quit()
        self.progress_root.destroy()
```

And the label part here, if you want~

```
sf_label_text_dic = {
    'main_progress_label': ['扫描文件中...  发现文件：', 'Scanning items...  Found item：'],
    'main_progress_label1': [['总进度：', '已完成'], ['Progress：', 'Completed']],
    'main_progress_label2': ['扫描文件中...', 'Scanning items...'],
    'current_file_label': ['等待中...', 'Waiting...'],
    'current_file_label1': ['同步中文件：', 'File in process：'],
    'exit_sync': ['''文件正在同步中，
确定中断同步进程并退出?''', '''Synchronization is in progress,
Are you sure to interrupt the process and exit?'''],
    'can_not_move_notice': ["""
无法被移动，请在关闭文件或移除重名文件后重试""", """
Couldn't be moved, Please try again after closing the file
or removing the duplicate file """]
    }

progress_root_label_dic = {
    'confirm_exit_text': ['''文件正在复制中，
确定中断进程并退出?''', '''The file is currently being copied,
Are you sure to interrupt the process and exit?''']
}
```

It sucks, as you can see......

So, help me write a more efficient code to implement the functions contained in the original code,
please~

Comment: If you are asking for a code review, this is not the place. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you have a specific problem or error that you need help with, please describe the issue and try to limit the code shared to the code that you think is causing the trouble, or that would allow someone here to reproduce the problem.